# ASP MVC ActionName in Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I´m using this overload of `Ajax.BeginForm()`:

```
(this AjaxHelper, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions):MvcForm
```

And it´s all good.

But now I need to add a attribute to my `<form>`-tag, so I need to send in `htmlAttributes`- ergo I need to use another overload of the `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

Here´s my problem: When I use the first overload, I get a correct href for the form, but with the second overload, I need to pass in a ActionName. I have tried passing in the real ActionName, and I get the wrong href. I´ve tried to pass in NULL value, and it´s still the wrong href (but the same as when I pass in the real ActionName ("Index")).

Is there any other method I could use to add my form-attribute or something to solve this? (I could of course add it with a javascript, like we did in the 90´s, but this is 2013...)

EDIT:
Here´s the overload I use now, that gives me the wrong href:

```
    Ajax.BeginForm("Index",null,new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", 
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "myform" }, 
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

Comment: Do you have your routes setup correctly to allow the automatic creation of the URLs correctly?

Comment: To be honest, no. And I suspect that this could be because I use a CMS (EPiServer), because what is wrong is with the ActionName specified I miss the country-branch like this: http://mysite.com/en/englishpage - with ActionName overload it becomes http://mysite.com/englishpage. EPiServer is providing me with the language-routings.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("Index","YourControllerName",null,new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod
 ="POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,UpdateTargetId = "myform"}, 
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the overload you want.

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("actionName", "controllername", null, ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions(), htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object>())
```

Specify your action and controller names.  You then specify null for route values and pass in the rest of your parameters.

Please note, declaring the parameters with argument name specification was just for illustration purposes.  This is the default order for this overload so you do not need to explicitly declare them as I have done.

Comment: This is the overload I used (that gives me a different href). Stupid of me not to add that in the question, I will edit it now.

Comment: In that case, use the overload that also includes the explicit controller name.  That way it can't point to the incorrect action